# ChartJS fill above and below line

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to fill the area above and below the line with 2 different colors. From the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/area.html#example-with-multiple-colors) I assumed the correct configuration is:

```
fill: {
  target: 'origin',
  above: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',   // Area will be red above the origin
  below: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)'    // And blue below the origin
}
```

But that only fills the area below the line using the color from the `above` field, behaving exactly as if the `target` was `start` rather than `origin`. Am I doing something wrong?